# while-loop doesn't execute in viewDidLoad (trying to iterate over firebase childrens)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database structure in firebase like this:

```
root {
0 {
test: "test"
lol: "lol"
}
1 {
test: "test"
lol: "lol"
}
}
```

etc.

Now in `viewDidLoad` I tried to print the items of each child:

```
var i = 1
    while i < numberOfRows {
        rootRef.child("\(i)").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snap) in
            print(snap.value!)
        })

        i += 1
    }
//(numberOfRows is equal to 4)
```

But it prints nothing. It doesn't print anything either if I only try to print `i`.

I tried for i in `0...numberOfRows`, too.

Comment: I would observe .value and not .childAdded.

Comment: I'm not sure how fast it will make the network call either, inside the loop. So I'd add a local array, appending each snapshot child to said array, then iterate through them.

Comment: Instead of calling observe method on ref , I suggest using observeSingleEvent , if you just have to show the listing.